# Does Dreamweaver add enctype="text/plain" to forms automatically?

Tags: forms, dreamweaver, enctype, dreamweaver-templates

I have some forms that post to a CGI script.  I set them up and they work perfectly on all browsers.  Then I leave them alone.

A few days later, after designers have updated the page, the forms no longer work and a mysterious

enctype="text/plain"

has been added to the form tag.

I didn't put it there, and the designers didn't put it there ( intentionally ).  There is no source control, and I don't use Dreamweaver.  I can't explain where it came from.

Does Dreamweaver add this attribute automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is "no".

It turns out that it was not Dreamweaver after all.  Someone had created a template where enctype="text/plain" and was reusing it.

Dreamweaver CS3 only gives these 2 choices for enctype:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> multipart/form-data.

Human error not software error ( this time ).

Answer (score 1):

My copy of Dreamweaver CS3 doesn't, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible, depending on the settings.  Dreamweaver has an option for setting the form's enctype attribute in design mode.  Perhaps it was changed by accident?

Comment: Any idea where that option to set a form's enctype in Design mode is set?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the properties panel, typically found at the bottom of the window in design view.

Comment: Dreamweaver did not let me down.  Dreamweaver only gives 2 choices - application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data.